# A coordinate-independent formula for a potential of an exact 2-form

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

If I somehow know that a given 1-form $\omega$ on a contractible set $U$ on a manifold $M$ is exact (there exist a 0-form $f$ such that $\omega=\rm{d}f$), then I can find $f$ from the following coordinate-independent formula:
$$ f(x) = \int_{x_0}^x \omega$$
where point $x_0$ and integration path can be arbitrarily chosen, as long as they are contained in $U$.

Let as assume that $\sigma$ is a exact 2-form on a contractible set $U$ on a manifold $M$. Is there an analogous coordinate-independent formula allowing to find its potential (the 1-form $\omega$ such that $\sigma=\rm{d}\omega$)? The only ones I've seen choose a specific coordinate system, or assume that $M=\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Yes, $1$-forms are particularly easy. You can write down something coordinate-independent, but you do need to integrate out the $dt$ when the null-homotopy is given by varying $t$ from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: Can you show what you mean?

Comment: Let $F\colon U\times [0,1]\to U$ be the contraction, so $F(x,1)=x$ and $F(x,0)=x_0$ (fixed). Let $t\in [0,1]$. The pullback $F^*\sigma$  has some $dt$ terms; we can contract against $\partial/\partial t$ (this gives a $1$-form with coefficients that are functions of $x$ and $t$). It can be checked that if we set $$\omega = \int_0^1 (\iota_{\partial/\partial t}\sigma)dt,$$ then $d\omega = \sigma$.

Comment: Excellent, that's exactly what I needed. As I understand, the fact that the potential is not unique is connected to the fact that cottraction $F$ can be chosen in many different ways, which creates various possible vector fields $\partial/\partial t$. But if I choose one of them, I can find a potential. Thanks.

I think this should be an answer, thn I could mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F\colon U\times [0,1]$ be a (smooth) contraction, so $F(x,1)=x$ for all $x$ and $F(x,0)=x_0$ (fixed). Let $t\in [0,1]$. The pullback $F^*\sigma$ has some $dt$ terms; we can contract against $\partial/\partial t$ (this gives a $1$-form with coefficients that are functions of $x$ and $t$). It can be checked that if we set
$$\omega = \int_0^1 \big(\iota_{\partial/\partial t} \sigma\big)dt,$$
then $d\omega = \sigma$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [generalized Stoke's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem):

$$\int_{\partial M} \omega = \int_{M} \sigma.$$

Where $\partial M$ is the boundary of the manifold $M$.

Comment: And how does it help me to define $\omega$ in any specific point? Or, considering that its value in one point can be arbitrary, how does it help me to define $\omega$ in the vicinity of any specific point?